# How to select rows where the ID exists in one table, but not another?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have 2 tables:

1) An Order table (which has `OrderNumber` as the Id)

2) An Items table which can have multiple rows and also has an `OrderNumber` column tying each row to the ord er row above.

Most orders have multiple rows in the Items table - but some do not and I need to pull a report of Orders with no associated Items rows.

I could do this on 2 queries in my PHP but there is clearly a smarter way to do it in MySQL. I understand JOINS but usually that's when there IS data in both tables. How do I tackle this if there ISN'T a tie in both?

Comment: you want to get the records from the order table with no match in the items table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a LEFT OUTER JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN, depending on what you need.. It would help if you post the 2 queries, or some sample data...

OUTER handles any data that isn't there

here is a link to help you out: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM Order
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Order.OrderNumber = Items.OrderNumber

Comment: Thanks for the guide and the snippet. Worked well and taught me more than just a copy and paste which I usually do on here (lazy as it is).

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your `Items` table primary key is `Items_Id`

```
SELECT * FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Items USING ( `OrderNumber` ) where Items.Items_Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ways listed above, I'd say that I'd use this structure:

```
SELECT * FROM Order where not exists (SELECT NULL FROM Items where OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber);
```

You can also add an index on OrderNumber column in Items for better performance:

```
CREATE INDEX Idx_Items on Items (OrderNumber);
```

Comment: joins are faster than subqueries. Database 101.

Comment: Thank you! The Create Index query was essential as my system bogged down. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, joins are faster, but firstly not always, and secondly they're not available sometimes (in dynamic sql for example when you need to add some dynamic filters).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a the `NOT IN` phrase for the where clause. This would get Order records who's Id's aren't in the Items table.

```
SELECT * FROM Order WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT OrderNumber FROM Items)
```

Comment: joins are faster than subqueries. Database 101.

Comment: True, but the goal is to get the result set of what orders don't have items, not what are the records of orders and the items that aren't theirs.  Logic 101. A LEFT OUTER JOIN will give you a much larger data set to work with, which would then require a where condition to cull through. Sometimes a readable solution, is more appropriate, especially for SQL beginners.

Comment: your claim about a "much larger data set" is false, because the output is the same with the proper WHERE restrictions. Also, the subquery will be most probably converted in a temp table and evaluated once for every Order entry, and believe me THIS will yeld a much dataset to extract informations from. Is this more readable? true. Is this a good suggestion for a beginner? nope.

Comment: I agree about the inefficiency of Sub-queries. Left Outer Join with the Where clause is the correct approach. I wrote a less efficient query for the sake of a beginner, and the temp table evaluation is something I want to investigate. Mostly, I wish your first comment was as constructive as your second.

Comment: I as well. Apologies. Thanks for the tmp table info, apparently this can be used for serious performance tuning.